# Facebook api call

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I am creating a website in PHP and i want to use login with Facebook in my website. I have created an app ID in Facebook developer. Facebook login is working but i want to retrieve email id which is used on Facebook login.

here is my JavaScript code :

```
$facebook.api("/me").then( 
  function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    alert("Welcome " + response.email);
  },
  function(err) {
    alert("Please log in");
  });
```

Output:
response.email is undefined. 
On console log i am getting an object like object {name:"xxx",id:"111"}

How to retrieve Facebook login email id?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook provides all the details which are public or approved by facebook. So in that case you cannot get email-id everytime. 
Suppose one user is not using email in his account or email is private, than you cannot get his email-id.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the user email, you will need to follow these steps:

- Set the `email` permission for your app.
- When you call `$facebook.api("/me")` try calling like this `$facebook.api("/me?fields=id,name,email")` by doing this you should get the email of the logged in person.

**Note:**

Even if you have set the `email` permission some user sign up for facebook using their mobile no. as username or some user want their email to be private by setting privacy, so, in that case you won't get the get the user email.

So in case you want to save user in database for future reference work on `id` as this is the unique identifier for that user.

In case you want user email and if fb doesn't provide it you can ask explicitly.

Hope this will help you.